# how to encode pass with sha1 and Base64?

Tags: android, base64, encode, sha1

I need provide hashing password with sha1 and Base64 like next:

```
base64(sha1(password))
```

here is what i tried for:

```
private static String convertToHex(byte[] data) { 
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        int halfbyte = (data[i] >>> 4) & 0x0F;
        int two_halfs = 0;
        do { 
            if ((0 <= halfbyte) && (halfbyte <= 9)) {
                buf.append((char) ('0' + halfbyte));
            }
            else {
                buf.append((char) ('a' + (halfbyte - 10)));
            }
            halfbyte = data[i] & 0x0F;
        } while(two_halfs++ < 1);
    } 
    return buf.toString();
} 


public static String SHA1(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    md.update(password.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, password.length());
    byte[] sha1hash = md.digest();
    return convertToHex(sha1hash);
}
```

and than :

```
String encodedPass = Base64.encodeToString(password.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

but this doesn't work correctly...
Maybe there some mistake or some much easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

the problem was next:
convertToHex(sha1hash) - return string, but for correct work of Base64 I was needed to put byte [] here:

```
Base64.encodeToString(byte[], Base64.DEFAULT);
```

so solution is pretty simple:

```
public static String encodePassword(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String result;
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        md.update(password.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, password.length());
        byte[] sha1hash = md.digest();
        result = Base64.encodeToString(sha1hash, Base64.DEFAULT);
        result = result.substring(0, result.length()-1);
        return result;
    }
```